# C++ Access to the overloaded constructor from Array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

```
class A{
  int a;
  int b;
  A(){}
  A(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b){}
 };
class B{
  A[3] a;
  public:
   void methodB();
};
B::methodB{
  a[0](1, 1); //I want array to use A(int, int)constructor not default one.
}
```

I tried to call overloaded constructor A(int, int) from Array in Class B and it just call A() constructor not A(int, int)
Why does it happening.?
And what should i do??

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it actually *builds* (unless you're posting about a build error). Don't re-type code into the question, copy and paste actual code instead.

Comment: `methodB` is not a constructor - you can't affect the construction of any member variables therefrom - that's already done and dusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-construct an object once it has already been constructed.

You have a few options:

- Use a constructor initializer list:

  ```
  class B
  {
      std::array<3, A> a;
  public:
      B() : a{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
      {}
  };
  ```
- Use a `std::vector` and insert properly constructed objects when needed

  ```
  class B
  {
      std::vector<A> a;
      ...
  };

  void B::methodB()
  {
      a.emplace_back(1, 1);
  }
  ```
- Use a vector and default-initialize all elements in the constructor initializer list

  ```
  class B
  {
      std::vector<A> a;
  public:
      B() : a{3, {1, 1}}
      {}
  };
  ```